# How can I stop Minecraft from crashing while going to fullscreen on the Intel HD3000 graphics?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using a laptop with both nVidia and Intel graphics cards. The Intel card is actually fast enough to play Minecraft, and I'd rather not use the nVidia card because it causes the battery life to drop to effectively zero. However, it seems I can't send the game to full screen while using the slower graphics card; it crashes instantly if I do.

How can I get the game to go into fullscreen mode?

Comment: Maybe it's not the video card, what are your specs ? Could be a RAM problem or JAVA that's not running well. Have tried updating JAVA ?

Comment: @Warface: This is a brand new Windows installation; I just installed the latest Java build. (And fullscreen works just fine if I switch to the nVidia card; I therefore find it hard to believe Java is the issue)

Comment: Can you run other apps fullscreen?

Comment: Can you please run Minecraft from the command line and see what error message it outputs?

Comment: @Bobby: I have since given the laptop to my little brother -- I don't have it anymore.

Comment: I see...sorry, I always forget to look at the Timestamps.

Comment: @Bobby: No problem. Glad you took a look at least :)

Answer (score 2):

You **probably can't**. It **probably** has to do with indirect rendering . The nvidia card is probably the one writing to the screen, and supports a high resolution. But if you try fullscreen, the intel graphics try to write directly on the screen, which wont work since the nvidia card is doing that, or because it doesn't support such a high resolution.
But try lowering resolution, see if that works.

Of course, this is guesswork, as I don't even know what model, drivers, settings, etc, you have.

**Suggestion:** Go to options -> video settings, select "power saver" mode, and use the nvidia card.

Comment: Don't think that's it - other games and things work, just not Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

What graphics settings are you using? The first thing you should try is reducing your graphics to minimum (fast graphics, tiny render distance, Smooth Lighting off etc.) and seeing if that works. If it does, turn things on until it stops working/goes slow. If it still doesn't run with all graphics set to minimum, you're probably out of luck.

One other thing that's worth checking is Advanced OpenGL - try with it on *and* off, as it seems to cause problems some of the time when it's on.

Comment: Doesn't matter what settings I choose in the game; it crashes attempting to go to full screen. Maximizing the window works fine.